# launchd won't run a loaded script on reboot

Tags: launchd

so i'm having a few troubles with launchd

I made this plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>mosek.mountd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/etc/mountd</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My problem is this. When i load the script manually:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/script.plist
```

It works like a charm. It load perfectly, and runs the script as it should.
now when I reboot, it loads the script as it should, but now the script won't start.
Though when I start the script

```
launchctl start mosek.mountd
```

it works. So it must be ignoring the "RunAtLoad" key, when it loads the script on reboot. Why does it do that, and how do I fix it?

cheers in advance

```
edit:
    I forgot to mention that I also made root the owner of the file by running:
         chmod root /Library/LaunchDaemons/script.plist
    and it still wouldn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your permissions. The file script.plist should look like this

`-rw-r--r--  1 wheel  410 16 ...`

From `man launchctl`

> Note that per-user configuration files (LaunchAgents) must be owned by the user loading them. All system-wide daemons (LaunchDaemons) must be owned by root. Configuration files must not be group- or world-writable.

Comment: Hi. sorry i forgot to mention that. i ran chmod root /Library/LaunchDaemons/script.plist, so I don't think that is the problem

Comment: the file permission looks like this: -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  404

Comment: please try these steps to debug your plist: 1. set the launcdctr log level to debug
`sudo launchctl log level debug` (debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert, emergency)

2. Tail the system.log
`tail -f /var/log/system.log`

3. set the launcdctr log level back to error
`sudo launchctl log level error`

from [obscured clarity](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.de/2011/02/debugging-launchd-configuration-on-mac.html)

Comment: I tried what you suggested. I unloaded the plist, set the loglevel to debug, loaded the plist, tail the system log. when I tailed the system log, there wasn't anything on my plist. does this mean it didn't run, cause it did, or does it mean, that there aren't any bugs in it?

Comment: I added a KeepAlive key, and that did the trick. But as far as I understand the KeepAlive key, it runs the process over and over again indefinitely. I wanted it to run a single time when the system rebooted, and not more then that

Comment: KeepAlive means that if the applications quits or crashes, launchd will restart it. Please see also [man launchd.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

My friend, I suggest a few modifications to the plist file:

Add:

```
<key>Program</key>
     <string>/where/the/script/you/want/to/be/executed/resides</string>
```

Then modify the ProgramArguments to reflect the 'basename' of the script -- its name without the full path, or 'dirname'.  I mean like this, assuming '/usr/local/bin/mosek.mountd.sh' to be the script you want run:

```
<key>Program</key>
     <string>/usr/local/bin/mosek.mountd.sh</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
          <string>mosek.mountd.sh</string>
          <string>/etc/mountd</string>
     </array>
```

This should resolve the problem.  Please let me know if this helps.

F.